# Ubuntu installation grub error

Tags: 16.04

I tried to install Ubuntu on a machine previously used by Windows, I’ve backed up the contents to a different partition and tried to install Ubuntu to sda3 and a message pops up after installation saying that Ubuntu won’t be bootable, and when I tried to boot it’s a black screen.

Link to some useful screenshots related to the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3h4oi.jpg

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, I've create a new partition in the Installation as EFI, so

I ended up with:

1) EFI Drive Partition of 32GB

2) Empty EXT4 Partition for Ubuntu

3) NTFS backup of Windows Files

this allowed me to not only install Ubuntu without errors, but directly boot to Ubuntu.

Comment: Your ESP - efi system partition does not have to be that large. Windows uses 100MB as default. We often suggest a little larger like 300 to 500MB if on a larger drive so you have room for future use. But you may find you have not used hardly any of your ESP.